# How to turn off automatic retry in Spring Integration Jms.inboundGateway

Tags: spring-integration, dsl, spring-java-config

I am using 
`spring 4.2.4.RELEASE` and
`spring-integration-java-dsl:1.1.2.RELEASE`

I have `Jms.inboundGateway` and some transformer. When **transformer fails** to transform a message, inbound gateway **retries again and again**. But I want to stop the entire flow in case of exception. 
 Is it possible to do?

This is my flow configuration:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow nonStop {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(Jms.inboundGateway(emsConnectionFactory)
                    .destination(myDestination)
                    .configureListenerContainer(spec -> spec
                            .sessionTransacted(true)
                            .subscriptionDurable(true)
                            .durableSubscriptionName(durableSubscriptionName)
                            .errorHandler((ErrorHandler) t -> {
                                t.printStackTrace();
                                throw new RuntimeException(t);
                            }))
                    .errorChannel(errorChannel)
                    .autoStartup(true)
                    .id(myNonStoppableFlow))
            .filter(...)
            .transform(...)
            .handle(Jms.outboundAdapter(emsConnectionFactory)
                             .destination(myOnotherDestination))
            .get();
}
```

One interesting notice. When `errorHandler` swallows an exception inbound gateway retires without any delay. When it throws Runtime exception there is delay about 5 seconds (which is not configured anywhere).

Answer (score 1):

That `retry` in JMS is called like `redelivery`: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074123/java-web-development/transaction-and-redelivery-in-jms.html.

So, any downstream exception makes for your message rollback and redelivery, which can be configured on Broker for the destination.

Actually if your `.errorChannel(errorChannel)` flow doesn't re-throw the exception, it will be treated as a `successful` handling and as commit.

From other side you should reconsider if you really need there a `Jms.inboundGateway()`. Because this one requires a **reply**, which doesn't look possible with your `Jms.outboundAdapter()` in the end.